# Cómo consultar contenido variables a través del Monitor.bat

Tags: genexus

Estamos desarrollando una app mobile offline con objetos Panel.
La misma a través de los servicios de una API Rest (/jderest) se contecta a un servidor AIS.
Desde el la app Genexus se envia un JSON para hacer el Request hacia el servicio de la API,
Y luego el servidor devuelve (Response) al servicio la información requerida también en formato JSON.

La consulta puntual es: cómo puedo hacer desde el Monitor (C:\Android-SDK\tools\monitor.bat) para encontrar en el logging con texto JSON enviado y el recibido?
Como no se puede debbuguer directo en el IDE de genexus colocando breakpoints a un Panel SD, entonces recurrí al Monitor.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero no encuentro el JSON de request y el JSON de response.
También generé el log a través de la consola de comandos, parandome en C:\Android-SDK\platform-tools y luego ejecutando:
adb logcat -v brief GeneXusApplication:D AndroidRuntime:E System.out:I *:S > MyLogFile.txt

Eso me generó y llego el archivo log en C:\Android-SDK\platform-tools\MyLogFile.txt pero dentro de él no encuentro lo que estoy el JSON de Request y el JSON de Response.

Cómo debo fijarme?

O debo generar un archivo plano a mano donde ir escribiendo el contenido de la variable string que contiene el texto de los JSON para poderlo revisar?

Cualquier orientación es bienvenida, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para ver los mensajes de la aplicación en la consola debes habilitar el log a nivel de la aplicación [ver el detalle aquí](https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?37846,HowTo%3A%20Enable%20logging%20for%20Smart%20Devices).
Poniendo "Default Log level" = Debug en el Main por ejemplo.

Luego si necesitas agregar mensajes propios puedes usar [la Api de Log](https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?37872,Log%20external%20object).
Escribiendo:

```
Log.Debug(&string)
```

o simplemente

```
msg(&string,status)
```